# Error handling while importing data through CSV

Tags: php, import-csv

I need to handle any error while importing data thought a `CSV` file. 
What i need to achieve is to show total row number of rows uploaded  successfully and error if any.

Below is the image of the wire frame that i need to show

[image]

Below is the code that I am currently using:

```
include_once("db_connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['import_data'])){    
    // validate to check uploaded file is a valid csv file
    $file_mimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$file_mimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){   
            $csv_file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');           
            //fgetcsv($csv_file);            
            // get data records from csv file
            while(($emp_record = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== FALSE){
                // Check if employee already exists with same email
              $c++;
              if($c != "1"){
                $sql_query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary, emp_age FROM emp WHERE emp_email = '".$emp_record[2]."'";
                $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                // if employee already exist then update details otherwise insert new record
                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultset)) {                     
                    $import_status = '?import_status=exists';
                } else{
                    $mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO emp (emp_name, emp_email, emp_salary, emp_age )VALUES('".$emp_record[1]."', '".$emp_record[2]."', '".$emp_record[3]."', '".$emp_record[4]."')";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_insert) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                    $import_status = '?import_status=success';
                }
              }

            }            
            fclose($csv_file);

        } else {
            $import_status = '?import_status=error';
        }
    } else {
        $import_status = '?import_status=invalid_file';
    }
}
header("Location: upload_employee_data_open_link.php".$import_status);
```

Comment: Now tell us - what's the problem?

Comment: how to store an error but let the system still continue the execution skipping that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Ignore is used to ignore any query related error. It will skip the error and pass on to the next query. Hope it helps someone